# Merge two DataColumns of type DateTime

Tags: c#

i have a datatable which contains two Datacolumns (date_start,date_sent) and i wanted to merge them into one single column (date_order) to then apply a sort like this:

```
DataRow[] dtSorted = dt.Select(null, "date_order DESC",DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Since whenever date_start is null, date_sent is not and vice versa, i tried the following expression to the datacolumn:

```
dt.Columns.Add("date_order", typeof(String), "IIF(date_start=NULL,date_sent,date_start)");
```

but its not working.Tried something like "ISNULL(date_start,date_sent),date_start" and "date_start + date_sent" but they didn't work either.

Can someone please tell me what expression i should use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the SQL COALESCE keyword, which returns the first non-null argument, e.g.:

```
SELECT COALESCE(date_order, date_sent) ...
```

That will return the first non-null out of date_order and date_sent

Comment: FYI, C# has a similar operator - ?? e.g. var aorb = a ?? b;

Comment: perfect, thanks. Still curious on how you'd do it using only the expression since COALESCE isn't recognized there

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in C#...[??](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is the Null Coalescing operator you should be looking for I think...basically equivalent to [isnull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) in tsql.